# Is $0$ a common point of $(0,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,0)$?

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to prove $\mathbb{R}$ is connected in the $K$-topology.
I've proved already that $(0,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,0)$ inherit the usual topology as subspaces of $\mathbb{R}_K$ and thus are connected. If 0 is a common point i'm done. Is it?

Comment: Shouldn't a common point be element of both sets?

Comment: What you should be looking at are their closures! A closure of a connected set is connected.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $\mathbb R=U\cup V$ with $U$ and $V$ $K$-open. Wlog. $0\in U$. Then some $(a,b)\setminus\{\frac1n\mid n\in\mathbb N\,\}$ with $a<0<b$ must be $\subseteq U$. Conclude that $U\cap(-\infty,0)\ne \emptyset$ and $U\cap(0,\infty)\ne \emptyset$ and by their connectedness $(-\infty,0)\subseteq U$, $(0,\infty)\subseteq U$, and of course we started with $0\in U$. So while you don't have an *immediate* overlap of $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,\infty)$, they are still "glued" together via a neighbourhood of $0$.